# Why does Spark application fail with “ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka” as uber-jar with sbt assembly?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to run a sample like [StructuredKafkaWordCount](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/StructuredKafkaWordCount.scala). I started with the [Spark Structured Streaming Programming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html).

My code is

```
package io.boontadata.spark.job1

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object DirectKafkaAggregateEvents {
  val FIELD_MESSAGE_ID = 0
  val FIELD_DEVICE_ID = 1
  val FIELD_TIMESTAMP = 2
  val FIELD_CATEGORY = 3
  val FIELD_MEASURE1 = 4
  val FIELD_MEASURE2 = 5

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 3) {
      System.err.println(s"""
        |Usage: DirectKafkaAggregateEvents <brokers> <subscribeType> <topics>
        |  <brokers> is a list of one or more Kafka brokers
        |  <subscribeType> sample value: subscribe
        |  <topics> is a list of one or more kafka topics to consume from
        |
        """.stripMargin)
      System.exit(1)
    }

    val Array(bootstrapServers, subscribeType, topics) = args

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("boontadata-spark-job1")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    // Create DataSet representing the stream of input lines from kafka
    val lines = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
      .option(subscribeType, topics)
      .load()
      .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
      .as[String]

    // Generate running word count
    val wordCounts = lines.flatMap(_.split(" ")).groupBy("value").count()

    // Start running the query that prints the running counts to the console
    val query = wordCounts.writeStream
      .outputMode("complete")
      .format("console")
      .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
  }

}
```

I added the following sbt files:

build.sbt:

```
name := "boontadata-spark-job1"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.2" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.0.2" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.0.2" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.0.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.0.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.1.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.10.1.1"

// META-INF discarding
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := { 
   {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
   }
}
```

I also added project/assembly.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

This creates a Uber jar with the non `provided` jars.

I submit with the following line:

```
spark-submit boontadata-spark-job1-assembly-0.1.jar ks1:9092,ks2:9092,ks3:9092 subscribe sampletopic
```

but I get this runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please find packages at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Third+Party+Projects
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:148)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceSchema(DataSource.scala:218)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo(DataSource.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingRelation$.apply(StreamingRelation.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:124)
        at io.boontadata.spark.job1.DirectKafkaAggregateEvents$.main(StreamingJob.scala:41)
        at io.boontadata.spark.job1.DirectKafkaAggregateEvents.main(StreamingJob.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.DefaultSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DataSource.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DataSource.scala:132)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$5.apply(DataSource.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$5.apply(DataSource.scala:132)
        at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:132)
        ... 18 more
16/12/23 13:32:48 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Is there a way to know which class is not found so that I can search the maven.org repo for that class.

The `lookupDataSource` source code seems to be at line 543 at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/83a6ace0d1be44f70e768348ae6688798c84343e/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSource.scala but I couldn't find a direct link with Kafka data source...

Complete source code is here: https://github.com/boontadata/boontadata-streams/tree/ad0d0134ddb7664d359c8dca40f1d16ddd94053f

Comment: complete source code is here: <https://github.com/boontadata/boontadata-streams/tree/ad0d0134ddb7664d359c8dca40f1d16ddd94053f>

Comment: Hi @jithinpt, please see comments in the answer marked as THE answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I tried like this it's working for me. Submit like this and let me know once you have any issues

```
./spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0 --class com.inndata.StructuredStreaming.Kafka --master local[*] /Users/apple/.m2/repository/com/inndata/StructuredStreaming/0.0.1SNAPSHOT/StructuredStreaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Hi, the weird thing is in benjguin's sbt "libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.0.2"" has already been there. Why you need to manually add "--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0"? I know it works, but I just don't know why it does not work without that.

Comment: I'd call it a workaround and does not explain why the uber-jar does not work. The root cause is `assemblyMergeStrategy` in `build.sbt` that discards all `META-INF` files incl. registrations. See my answer below.

Comment: The docs aren't clear on which dependencies should be marked provided. Seems spark-sql-kafka is not one of them. Remove the provided tag from pom.xml/build.sbt and it works

Answer (score 39):

The issue is the following section in `build.sbt`:

```
// META-INF discarding
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := { 
   {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
   }
}
```

It says that all `META-INF` entires should be discarded, including the "code" that makes data source aliases (e.g. `kafka`) work.

But the `META-INF` files are very important for `kafka` (and other aliases of streaming data sources) to work.

For `kafka` alias to work Spark SQL uses [META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister) with the following entry:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider
```

`KafkaSourceProvider` [is responsible to register](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaSourceProvider.scala#L49) `kafka` alias with the proper streaming data source, i.e. [KafkaSource](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaSource.scala).

Just to check that the real code is indeed available, but the "code" that makes the alias registered is not, you could use the `kafka` data source by the fully-qualified name (not the alias) as follows:

```
spark.readStream.
  format("org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider").
  load
```

You will see other problems due to missing options like `kafka.bootstrap.servers`, but...*we're digressing*.

A solution is to `MergeStrategy.concat` all `META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister` (that would create an uber-jar with all data sources, incl. the `kafka` data source).

```
case "META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister" => MergeStrategy.concat
```

Comment: Actually sounds like I managed to make it work with your suggestion. Just had to order the "case" in the merge strategy and put that at the top.

Comment: Should I still retain the case `PathList("META-INF" , ...)` after applying `case "META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister" => MergeStrategy.concat`?

Comment: They're different patterns so it depends on your app actually.

Comment: I was able to run just by replacing kafka by org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider along with making an uber jar with maven shade plugin . Thanks a lot @JacekLaskowski

Comment: Great! You don't need "replacing kafka by org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider". Switch it back.

Answer (score 4):

### This is in view of Jacek Laskowski's answer.

Those of you building your project on maven can try this out.
Add the line mentioned below to your maven-shade-plugin.

*META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister*

I've put down the plugin code for the pom file as an example to show where to add the line.

---

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>
                            META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister
                        </resource>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-uber</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

Please excuse my formatting skills.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I also got this error while compiling with sbt, and the cause was that `sbt assembly` was not including the `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11` artifact as part of the fat jar.

(I would be very welcome to comments here. The dependency was not specified a scope, so it should not be assumed to be "provided").

So I changed to deploying a normal (slim) jar and including the dependencies with the `--jars` parameters to spark-submit.

In order to gather all dependencies in one place, you can add `retrieveManaged := true` to your sbt project settings, or you can, in the sbt console, issue:

```
> set retrieveManaged := true
> package
```

That should bring all dependencies to the `lib_managed` folder.

Then you can copy all those files (with a bash command you can for example use something like this

```
cd /path/to/your/project

JARLIST=$(find lib_managed -name '*.jar'| paste -sd , -)

spark-submit [other-args] target/your-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --jars "$JARLIST"
```

Comment: Yes, this happened on Spark 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using spark 2.1 and facing the very same problem 
my workaround is

1)  `spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0`

2) `cd ~/.ivy2/jars` here you are ,all the needed jars are in this folder now

3) copy all the jars in this folder to all the nodes(can create a specific folder holding them)

4) add the folder name  to `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.driver.extraClassPath` ,e.g. `spark.driver.extraClassPath=/opt/jars/*:your_other_jars`

5 `spark-submit --class ClassNm --Other-Options YourJar.jar` works fine now

Answer (score 1):

I am using gradle as a build tool and the shadowJar plugin to create the uberJar.
The solution was simply to add a File

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister
```

to the project.

In this file you need to put, line by line, the class names of the DataSources you use, in this case it would be `org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider` (find that class name for example [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister))

The reason is that Spark uses the java [ServiceLoader](https://itnext.io/java-service-provider-interface-understanding-it-via-code-30e1dd45a091) in it's internal dependency management mechanisms.

Full example [here](https://github.com/falcowinkler/spark-example).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by downloading the jar file to the driver system. From there, I supplied the jar to spark submit with --jar option.

Also to be noted is that i was packaging the whole spark 2.1 environment in my uber jar (since my cluster is still on 1.6.1)  For some reason, its not picked up when included in uber jar.

> spark-submit --jar /ur/path/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0 --class
>   ClassNm --Other-Options YourJar.jar

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old thread, I faced this issue with Pyspark 2.3.3 on Hortonworks 3.1.5 so I thought maybe it can help others.
The following jars are required for spark streaming integration with Kafka 2.

**Note**: Please download appropriate jars according to Spark & Kafka's version.

- [Kafka-clients](https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/2.0.0.3.1.4.0-315/kafka-clients-2.0.0.3.1.4.0-315.jar)
- [spark-streaming-kafka](https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.2.3.1.4.0-315/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.4.0-315.jar)
- [spark-streaming-kafka-*-assembly](https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11/2.3.2.3.1.4.0-315/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.4.0-315.jar)
- [spark-sql-kafka](https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.2.3.1.4.0-315/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.2.3.1.4.0-315.jar)