# Why does spark-submit fail to find kafka data source unless --packages is used?

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to integrate Kafka in my Spark app, here is my POM file required entries:

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.stream.kafka.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Corresponding artifact versions are:

```xml
<kafka.version>0.10.2.0</kafka.version>
<spark.stream.kafka.version>2.2.0</spark.stream.kafka.version>
```

I have been scratching my head over:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

I also tried supplying the jar with `--jars` parameter, however it is not helping. What am I missing here?

Code:

```java
private static void startKafkaConsumerStream() {

        Dataset<HttpPackage> ds1 = _spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", getProperty("kafka.bootstrap.servers"))
                .option("subscribe", HTTP_FED_VO_TOPIC)
                .load() // Getting the error here
                .as(Encoders.bean(HttpPackage.class));

        ds1.foreach((ForeachFunction<HttpPackage>)  req ->System.out.print(req));

    }
```

And _spark is defined as:

```
_spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName(_properties.getProperty("app.name"))
                .config("spark.master", _properties.getProperty("master"))
                .config("spark.es.nodes", _properties.getProperty("es.hosts"))
                .config("spark.es.port", _properties.getProperty("es.port"))
                .config("spark.es.index.auto.create", "true")
                .config("es.net.http.auth.user", _properties.getProperty("es.net.http.auth.user"))
                .config("es.net.http.auth.pass", _properties.getProperty("es.net.http.auth.pass"))
                .getOrCreate();
```

My imports are:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
```

However when I run my code as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303037/spark-2-0-2-sql-streaming-failed-to-find-data-source-kafka) and which is with the package option:

```sh
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0
```

It works

Comment: I tried to add whole details however I cant submit the question with more code. the page does not allow me to! However please specify what info you might require apart from the above, I will specify.

Comment: The way you try to access Kafka withing your project, as it seems to lack something

Comment: remove kafka dependency = org.apache.kafka

Answer (score 5):

Spark Structured Streaming supports Apache Kafka as the streaming source and sink using the external [kafka-0-10-sql](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql) module.

`kafka-0-10-sql` module is not available to Spark applications that are submitted for execution using `spark-submit`. The module is external and to have it available you should define it as a dependency.

Unless you use `kafka-0-10-sql` module-specific code in your Spark application you don't have to define the module as a `dependency` in `pom.xml`. You simply don't need a **compilation dependency** on the module since no code uses the module's code. You code against interfaces which is one of the reasons why Spark SQL is so pleasant to use (i.e. it requires very little to code to have fairly sophisticated distributed application).

`spark-submit` however will require `--packages` command-line option that you've reported it worked fine.

> However when I run my code as mentioned here and which is with the package option:
>
> ```
> --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0
> ```

The reason it worked fine with `--packages` is that you have to tell Spark infrastructure where to find the definition of `kafka` format.

That leads us to the other "issue" (or a requirement) to run streaming Spark applications with Kafka. You have to specify the **runtime dependency** on `spark-sql-kafka` module.

You specify a runtime dependency using `--packages` command-line option (that downloads the necessary jars after you `spark-submit` your Spark application) or creating a so-called uber-jar (or a fat-jar).

That's where `pom.xml` comes to play (and that's why people offered their help with `pom.xml` and the module as a `dependency`).

So, first of all, you have to specify the dependency in `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And the last but not least, you have to build an uber-jar that you configure in `pom.xml` using [Apache Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html).

With Apache Maven Shade Plugin you [create an Uber JAR](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) that will include all the "infrastructure" for `kafka` format to work, inside the Spark application jar file. As a matter of fact, the Uber JAR will contain all the necessary runtime dependencies and so you could `spark-submit` with the jar alone (and no `--packages` option or similar).

Comment: Despite adding " --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0" , I still get the same " Failed to find data source:kafka" error . Could you please tell me what else could be the reason ?

Comment: @Bharathi There could be many reasons for this and without looking at your case with more details it's hard to answer it in a comment. Can you please ask a separate question and leave the link here? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks . I resolved it . There seemed to be a minute syntax difference in the path between scala and python.

Answer (score 1):

Add below dependency to your `pom.xml` file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Update your dependencies and versions. Below given dependencies should work fine:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

PS: Note provided scope in first two dependencies.

Comment: This should work. Can you make sure user has access to jar files which you are enlisting in --jars option? Also, try creating fat jar and check whether that works

Comment: This doesnt work!