# How to get Spark/Kafka org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0 Dependency working in Maven pom file?

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

This question has been already discussed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303037/why-does-spark-application-fail-with-classnotfoundexception-failed-to-find-dat) however at time of writing I don't have enough reputation to make a comment on Algomeisters solution (which didn't end up working for me)

I have a spark job that uses Kafka and structured streaming. Thus it requires I have a dependency of the `spark-sql-kafka-0-10` module.

[Jacek Laskowski](https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/spark-structured-streaming-book/blob/master/spark-sql-streaming-KafkaSource.adoc) has said that you must include this package in the Spark submit command line option

> Structured Streaming support for Kafka is in a separate
>   spark-sql-kafka-0-10 module (aka library dependency).
>
> spark-sql-kafka-0-10 module is not included by default so you have to
>   start spark-submit (and "derivatives" like spark-shell) with
>   --packages command-line option to "install" it.

This I have done, below is my spark submit

```
SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10 spark2-submit \
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0 \
--class MyApp.MainClassPath \
--master local[4] \
MySparkApp-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

However, I don't think this is a good option, every time I run this jar it has to redownload the dependency. If for some reason this dependency is unavailable my application will no longer function. I am using **Maven** as a package manager and I have this package in my pom file however it doesn't work.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I try to run the spark job and remove the "--packages" option I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Failed to find data source: kafka. Please find packages at 
http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

which is caused by

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.DefaultSource
```

Thus I tried to include the solution provide by Algomeister using the Maven-Shade plugin however it did not work. I get the below error!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:330)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:263)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:318)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:230)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:977)
        at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:77)
        at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:160)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:454)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:695)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

It'd be great if we can have a working solution for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below maven file which uses shade plugin. Sample class is from `spark-2.2.0` examples - [JavaStructuredKafkaWordCount](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.2/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/streaming/JavaStructuredKafkaWordCount.java).

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>structured-kafka-word-count</groupId>
<artifactId>structured-kafka-word-count</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                 <resource>META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>org.apache.spark.examples.sql.streaming.JavaStructuredKafkaWordCount</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You can run it using `spark-submit` command like below.

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.sql.streaming.JavaStructuredKafkaWordCount --master local[2] structured-kafka-word-count-1.0.0.jar localhost:9092 subscribe mytopic
```

Comment: Excellent this works thank you. Could you give an explanation in simple terms what is going on in <artifact>*:*</artifact>, the <excludedes> with the  META files, and also the <transformers>?

Comment: You can refer to http://zhentao-li.blogspot.com/2012/06/maven-shade-plugin-invalid-signature.html and https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-shade-plugin-2.0/examples/resource-transformers.html